# Minimal python example using BufferedReader acting strangely

Tags: python, stream

See below the Minimal python example using io.BufferedReader which is acting very strangely.

Results are not consistent between the 3 calls.  2 work, and the last one, the most important one does not.  I have been looking at this too long and I don't see the problem.  Maybe I am doing something wrong I am missing.  Please take a look.  I am using Python 2.7.15+ on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS.

Note: Results are in the ### comment below the lines which produce output.

```
from io import BytesIO, StringIO, BufferedReader, DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE


class MDReader(BufferedReader):

  def __new__(cls, thingtoread, buffer_size=DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE):
    iothing = BytesIO(thingtoread) \
        if isinstance(thingtoread, str) \
        else StringIO(thingtoread) \
        if isinstance(thingtoread, unicode) \
        else thingtoread
    print iothing
    return iothing and BufferedReader.__new__(cls, iothing, buffer_size)

text = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'

mdr0 = BufferedReader.__new__(MDReader, BytesIO(text), DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE)
### <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7f348d06bbf0>

mdr1 = MDReader(BytesIO(text), DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE)
### <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7f348d06ba70>

mdr2 = MDReader(text, DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE)
### Traceback (most recent call last):
###   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
###   File "./foo.py", line 19, in <module>
###     mdr2 = MDReader(text, DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE)
### AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'readable'
```

Comment: What are the results? what do yo mean by *doesn't work*?

Comment: he means the object `mdr2` throws an error unlike `mdr1` and `mdr0`.

Comment: @Guy the results are inline with the code as a comment beginning with '###'

Comment: I very much expect it is __init__'s that is causing the problem.  I will check it out.

Answer (score 0):

if you replace the return in the __new__ with:

```
  self = iothing and BufferedReader.__new__(cls, iothing, buffer_size)
  cls.__init__(self, iothing, buffer_size)
  return self

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    print '__init__', args
    print '__init__', kwargs
```

then it behaves correctly.  Had nothing to to do with anything except I forgot to handle the __init__.  Or even better just move the argument handling code to the __init__ and remove the __new__.

Sorry for posting this.  I think I just didn't see the obvious because I was looking for something with the values.  Doh!